# Jenkins Job Builder - Cmake build-tool-invocations ignored

Tags: command-line, cmake, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

Here is what I am trying since couple of days:

1. Created a job using Jenkins-job-builder.
2. Created a cmake config and
   everything works except for build-tool-invocation.

The build-tool-invocation is ignored when configuring. Please find in the attached image; build tool cannot be configured using the below code.

Snapshot: 

 *- cmake:*

```
       source-dir:             ../
       working-dir:            /build
       install-dir:            install
       build-type:             CustomReleaseType
       generator:              Unix Makefiles
       installation-name:      CMake custom install
       preload-script: '/home/jenkins/cmake.preload'
       clean-build-dir:        true
       build-tool-invocations:
         - use-cmake: true
           arguments: 'clean'
           environment-variables: |
             DESTDIR=${WORKSPACE}/artifacts/dir
             URL=http://www.example.org/
```

[Add-build-tool-invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcecc.png)

Any similar experience? Is this a bug in the Job-builder plugin or something to do with my .yaml file?

Comment: `This tab is probably ignored when configuring`. What does 'this' refer to, I see no tab, nor did you mention tab before (or after that line). This makes no sense. Please edit your file (and suppress any urge to put "EDIT:" or "UPDATE:" in the text and make it clear where "this tab" is referring to.

Comment: I edited my question. Can you please answer me on this regard? Thank you in advance